# where is @Equals annotation in playframework 2.0?

Tags: validation, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to validate the equality of password with confirmPassword field in a registration form.
I am aware that in v.1(precisely v.1.2.4),  you can do this using @Equals("confirmPassword") annotation.
However the same functionality seems to be missing in v2.0. 
Am I missing out on something or v2.0 doesn't implement this anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Forms Validation](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaForms) for Play 2.0, specifically the `Constraints` section. The `play.data.validation.Constraints` class contains several built-in validation annotations according to the documentation. They made a lot of changes between the 1.* and 2.* versions.

Comment: i have already looked at it before. but i guess what i want is a confirmation that @Equals is NOT implemented in 2.* so i can  get on with my own implementation or better yet a link showing a clean way of doing equals validation of 2 fields in 2.* which the link you have provided does not mention.

Comment: @iecanfly `@Equals` is NOT implemented in Play 2. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.3/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.html, use custom `validate()` method from **j.w.r's** link to check i passwords are the same and probably also if they are strong enough.